# override bootstrap css without !important tag

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I've searched around a bit and can't find a clean solution.

Bootstrap is overriding my custom css. I have ensured that my custom script file is below the bootstrap css file, but this still doesn't solve the issue.

If i tack the `!important` tag on to a `font-size`, that works. I just feel like going through and putting `!important` after everything is sloppy and time consuming. Thoughts?

I am running a rails app, if that is germane to my issue.

Script

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins' rel='stylesheet' type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.scss">
```

CSS

```
h1 {
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 5.5em !important;
}
```

Comment: Please show your HTML, and the CSS you're trying to apply to it.

Comment: Because Bootstrap has higher [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) on its classes, so you can't override them without using `!important` or using the same specificity used by Bootstrap

Comment: added my html and css

Comment: try to add your css first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [CSS specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) to override the default **Bootstrap** CSS without using `!important`. So your `h1` tag could be defined using the following:

### CSS

```
body h1 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 5.5em;
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

Just adding `body` before any of your CSS declarations should override the **Bootstrap** CSS. See [this Code Pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EWRZzQ) to see an example with your code.